# Problems trying to implement a Link tag to go back, but it works with browser's back button?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have 3 nested components. The data displayed in the 2nd one is depending on your choice in the 1st one, and the data displayed in the 3rd one is a result of a choice in the 2nd one.

I'm using react-router and also redux. When I put a  `<Link>` inside of the 2nd component to go back to the 1st one, it's all good, but the problem that I'm facing is when I implement a link tag in 3rd component to do the same (go back to the 2nd), it throws the error you see in the pic.

Additionally, when I try to do the same by using the browser back button, I don't have issues. I'm confused. I read a lot about it, experimented with withRouter, etc. Error remains.

[image: error that is popping up]

Comment: Can you show us the (possibly stripped down) code please? (At least ReportsDetails would be helpful because the error is in there.)

Comment: Thank you, man, for reaching out.
I only needed a way to go back without losing my previous state.
I post an answer myself. It worked for me.
You can tell me if it's a good practice?
Cheers!

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution! I was basically curious where the error msg came from... For the context solution, looks reasonable but I've never worked with the context. So I'm the wrong person to ask, sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this as a solution. For future reference here's what I did:

```
static contextTypes = {
                router: () => {}
              }                
    onClick={this.context.router.history.goBack}>
```

Cheers!